# How can I configure SocketCAN to a specific interface?

Tags: linux, sockets, interface, can-bus, socketcan

I'm using a Beaglebone Black with two CAN interfaces as SocketCAN. How can I link i.e the interface can0 to my hardware DCAN0? I need to use both sockets parallel but didn't find to configure the interfaces.

Comment: Could you add `ip addr` output to your question? I.e. can you see both `can0` and `can1` interfaces?

Comment: Yes, I can see both interfaces and can receive packets on both, but can only transmit on can0.
Now I have DCAN0 on can0 and DCAN1 on can1, because I enabled the interfaces in this order. My question is now, where the interfaces know, on which can (DCAN0 or DCAN1) they have to send.

Comment: I think this depends on your Device Tree source file. If you have only one CAN interface either DCAN0 or DCAN1 you'll get `can0`. If you have both, then you'll get DCAN0 assigned to `can0` and DCAN1 assigned to `can1` automatically. So sending on `can1` would send the packets to DCAN1.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the mapping of interfaces to devices via 
`ls -la /sys/class/*`
while using the corresponding subdirectory for your CAN device.
Ethernet devices for example are listed in `/sys/class/net/`, terminal emulators/devices in `/sys/class/tty/`, etc.